# Is there any way to inject validation constraints in symfony

Tags: validation, symfony, dependency-injection, constraints

I want to validate few parameters in my own bundle. It's easy to inject validator service, but it seems that I will still have to "use" constraints classes.

Is there is a way to avoid hardcoding constraint dependencies?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you show us the code revelant to the question? And what is your expected behaviour?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's say that $validator is our injected validator. Then to validate value I need to do something like that:

    $validator->validateValue('Moo', new Email());

Where Email is class inside 'Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\' namepath.

But to do it in that way I will have to hardcode that exact name path into my service, thus coupling it not only to the framework, but actually implementation in the current version.

Comment: Yes, your application then have a *dependency* toward the `Validator` component, this doesn't seem to be a problem. If you don't want to *"hardcode"* the classname, you might want to create an `Acme\Validator\Validation\EmailInterface` which ANY email validator should implement in order to work with your application. But again, I don't see why you need this.

Comment: Because I don't really have a dependency towards specific Validator. My code accepts ANY validator that have validateValue method basically. Path hardcoding is not the same - because if, for example Symfony will decide to move some validators to another namespace (which already happened) - my code will break.

Comment: @parnas at first: Symfony will never break before releasing 3.0. Secondly, you can never make your code so flexible that it doesn't have any dependency on any class at all. So you just have to life with it, or inject the constraints in your class but that's way to much overhead for something usefull imo

Comment: I'm using Symfony since 0.6.4. I don't believe in no "will never break" :) What I was looking for is some kind of constraint factory service that I can inject. There is even a code to convert strings into constraints in Validator AbstractLoader class (used by FileLoader), so, most likely, what I would have to do is to built my service that will extend that Loader. But what I was wondering about is if I'm missing something already built for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Define your constraints as services.

```
$emailConstraint = $this->get('my_email_constraint');
$this->validator->validateValue('Moo', $emailConstraint);
```

So now if you decide to use a new super duper email validator, all you need to do is to update your service file.

Comment: It's not "my constraints". It's symfony built-in ones.

Comment: ??? Using services isolates your client code from know exactly which constraint class is being used and hence avoids the need to hard code dependencies.  Consider updating your question with an example of how you want things to work.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I need to write service for EACH symfony constraint that I want to use? Check comments to the question - there is a small example there.

Comment: That is exactly what I am suggesting.  Not hard.  Just tuck them away in their own service file somewhere.  If you want, you can even use parameters for the class name which means that each app can override as necessary.  Keep in mind that the requirement is to validate a "few parameters" so there should not be that many.

Comment: If I would decide to go "write my own service" way I would much rather write a factory service to get any constrain I may need, instead of writing a service for each one. What I was wondering if there is a built-in way to do that already (that I have missed). Seems no.